# Notepad++ удалить id="..." вместе с содержимым

Tags: notepad++

Есть куча текстов где у каждого абзаца код с содержимым вида id="p..."
Нужно удалить id="p...", вместо точек цифры. Заранее спасибо, кто поможет!

Comment: Добавьте образец входных данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Нужно выбрать режим "Поиск/Замена"
- В "Режим поиска" выбрать радиокнопку "Регуляр.выраже."
- В поле поиска набрать следующее `id="p\d+"`

Эта регулярка будет находить все твои комбинации...

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!!!!!